# Set the weights of a neural networks?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am coding right now an DRL algorithm that uses the principle of Double DQN with a model and a target which gets updated over time.

So in my code i go this line:

```
self.q_next.set_weights(self.q_eval.get_weights())
```

Which results in the following error message:

ValueError: You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "d3qn_1" with a weight list of length 10, but the layer was expecting 0 weights. Provided weights: [array([[[[ 0.04574016,  0.03492326, -0.04824715, ...

Why can i not set the weights of one network to the other?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: **the layer was expecting 0 weights**. If `q_next` is a tensorflow layer, then you can write `q_next.trainable_weights` to see if it has any trainable weights or not

Comment: It should not be just a layer. I want to update the weights of my target_network with the weights of q_eval. Why could it be that the layer is expecting 0 weights?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by building the q_next model first, but you need to know the dimension of your inputs ahead.

For example:

```
self.target_model.build((None, 80, 80, 1))
self.target_model.set_weights(self.model.get_weights())
```